# Services that offer Live Streaming and DRM

Tags: video, streaming, live, drm

I wanted to live stream content that requires DRM (an official movie). Does anyone have experience on best services to leverage together to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft DRM + Windows Media Server is well proven. There are a few resellers of Microsoft DRM, by which you can get it done affordably.

http://www.ezdrm.com/html/Microsoft/Windows_Media/WMDRM/about_WMDRM.asp

there is also a free trial to test.

http://www.ezdrm.com/html/try_free.asp